# Unable to boot to Xubuntu 14.x after Thinkpad x230 BIOS Reset Defaults

Tags: boot, xubuntu, uefi, thinkpad

All of this started when my Centrino wireless device stopped working (it thinks radio is off). So I decided to reset BIOS defaults to see if that helps. But I ended up with an unbootable system... Now I have two problems! So my UEFI is shot. Here's the diag output of boot-repair:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23817363/

I have three partitions:

/dev/sda1 (UEFI)

/dev/sda2 /boot

/dev/sda3 root (crypto LUKS)

I've attempted many tricks and tips from articles online like reinstalling grub, the grub uefi re-installation, etc. But none have helped. When I get to the boot device selection screen on my Thinkpad and pick my SSD drive, it just quickly goes back to the boot screen.

Can anyone please help?
Thank you

Comment: What's the error message from youresume screen when  boot fails?

Comment: Just a blinking cursor and it blinks just once at most before it quickly takes me back to the bootable device screen again. So it all happens in a flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that boot-repair repairs the grub files, local EFI files, and partitioning only. But what it doesn't do is actually change the UEFI firmware to add the new UEFI boot option, which was yanked out when I reset the BIOS to defaults. Thankfully I came across efibootmgr to do just that (which is used by boot-repair to outline the boot options).

Here's the command I used to restore the boot entry:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L "Ubuntu Main" -l "\efi\ubuntu\grubx64.efi"
```

- `-d /dev/sda -p 1` is equivalent to saying my /boot/efi partition is /dev/sda1
- `-L` is just an arbitrary string you use to remember which boot option you just added
- `-l "\efi\ubuntu\grubx64.efi"` is an actual file that links your boot option to your actual boot files.

Here's my file layout:

```
# ls -R /boot/efi/
/boot/efi/:
EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
ubuntu

/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu:
grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  MokManager.efi  shimx64.efi
```

Crisis avoided!